# Delete multiple records in codeigniter without using form

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I am trying to delete multiple records in codeigniter 4, I am passing this in codeigniter but that can not work

Pass this function in Model

```
public function delete_user($id)
{
    $db = Database::connect();
    $db->where_in('id', $id);
    $db->delete('user');
}
```

Pass this function in Controller

```
public function multiple_delete()
{
    $id = $_POST['check_box'];
    $model = new UserModel();
    $model->delete_user($id);
}
```

In the controller $Id value successfully find.

Comment: Yes, so? How is that code related to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach loop delete all records on by one as blow.

Change your model as below.

```
public function delete_user($id)
{
    foreach($id as $key => $value){ 
     $db = Database::connect();
     $db->where('id', $id);
     $db->delete('user');
    }
}
```